# how to hide internal function calls in profvis() Flame graph running on a shinyapp

Tags: r, shiny

I am using the excellent `profvis` package to debug my shiny app's performance bottlenecks. The documentation of `profvis()` by **wch** (the author) mentions that to get rid of the over bloated stack we can remove several dozens of internal functions that crowd the chart, by checking on a button:

> **hide internal function calls**
>   *(this is under **options** dropdown on the top right of the rstudio console, just below Publish)*

Despite clicking on the above radio button my shiny app flame graph shows a tower of internal function calls. Attaching a screenshot.
[image: Flame Graph]

My question is how to get rid of the dozens of internal calls so that I can focus on my functions.

The closest problem to this that I could search was here: 
(https://github.com/rstudio/profvis/issues/102).
But this seems to be unresolved too.